# ''Juego de Solitario'' modo simple, con listas en Lenguaje C

Tags: c, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Es mas que quedo por si me pueden dar consejos de como implementarlo.

Estoy empezando en este tema de las estructuras de datos.

El enunciado dice lo siguiente:

> El tablero constará de seis columnas con cartas y un espacio para indicar cual es la carta al tope de la baraja.

Ejemplo:"Tablero"
Siguiente carta: 7R

> 6N 5N KR 4N QR 2N.

Las opciones son Poner carta en columna, mover carta desde columna, Siguiente carta.

Comment: Esta pregunta se está discutiendo en [meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/811/7242). Sergio, si tienes otra pregunta, aunque sea parecida, lo mejor es realizar *otra* pregunta y mantener esta como estaba.

Comment: Tal y como se ha comentado, si ahora tienes una pregunta **diferente** a la original, deberías abrir una nueva pregunta sobre la siguiente duda que tengas. He devuelto la pregunta a un estado anterior por ese motivo.

Answer (score 6):

> si me pueden dar consejos de como implementarlo

Mi consejo es usar un arreglo de enumerados y hacer algo de magia con bits. Los palos son Clubs (♣ Negro), Spades (♠ Negro), Diamonds (♦ Rojo) y Hearts (♥ Rojo). Pudiendo combinar alternativamente Rojo con Negro independientemente del palo, así que podría ser buena idea codificar el color del palo en el enumerado.

Asumiendo un enumerado de 8 bits, podríamos usar el bit de mayor peso para indicar rojo o negro y los bits 4 y 5 para codificar el palo:

```
 #define ROJO  0x80
 #define NEGRO 0x00

 #define CLUBS    0x00
 #define SPADES   0x10
 #define DIAMONDS 0x20
 #define HEARTHS  0x30

 typedef enum
 {
      NINGUNA_CARTA = 0,
      C1 = CLUBS | NEGRO | 1,  S1 = SPADES | NEGRO | 1,  D1 = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 1,  H1 = HEARTHS | ROJO | 1,
      C2 = CLUBS | NEGRO | 2,  S2 = SPADES | NEGRO | 2,  D2 = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 2,  H2 = HEARTHS | ROJO | 2,
      C3 = CLUBS | NEGRO | 3,  S3 = SPADES | NEGRO | 3,  D3 = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 3,  H3 = HEARTHS | ROJO | 3,
      C4 = CLUBS | NEGRO | 4,  S4 = SPADES | NEGRO | 4,  D4 = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 4,  H4 = HEARTHS | ROJO | 4,
      C5 = CLUBS | NEGRO | 5,  S5 = SPADES | NEGRO | 5,  D5 = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 5,  H5 = HEARTHS | ROJO | 5,
      C6 = CLUBS | NEGRO | 6,  S6 = SPADES | NEGRO | 6,  D6 = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 6,  H6 = HEARTHS | ROJO | 6,
      C7 = CLUBS | NEGRO | 7,  S7 = SPADES | NEGRO | 7,  D7 = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 7,  H7 = HEARTHS | ROJO | 7,
      C8 = CLUBS | NEGRO | 8,  S8 = SPADES | NEGRO | 8,  D8 = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 8,  H8 = HEARTHS | ROJO | 8,
      C9 = CLUBS | NEGRO | 9,  S9 = SPADES | NEGRO | 9,  D9 = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 9,  H9 = HEARTHS | ROJO | 9,
      CJ = CLUBS | NEGRO | 10, SJ = SPADES | NEGRO | 10, DJ = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 10, HJ = HEARTHS | ROJO | 10,
      CQ = CLUBS | NEGRO | 11, SQ = SPADES | NEGRO | 11, DQ = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 11, HQ = HEARTHS | ROJO | 11,
      CK = CLUBS | NEGRO | 12, SK = SPADES | NEGRO | 12, DK = DIAMONDS | ROJO | 12, HK = HEARTHS | ROJO | 12,
 } cartas;
```

Con este enumerado, tendríamos por ejemplo...

```
   |colr|     palo     |      numero       |
   |bit7|bit6|bit5|bit4|bit3|bit2|bit1|bit0|
 1♣|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  1 | = 1
 2♠|    |    |    |  1 |    |    |  1 |    | = 18
 7♦|  1 |    |  1 |    |    |  1 |  1 |  1 | = 167
 Q♥|  1 |    |  1 |  1 |  1 |    |  1 |  1 | = 187
```

Cuando intentes mover una carta desde una columna, deberás *leer* el bit de color y comprobar que éste sea diferente al destino, para ello usa unas máscaras:

```
#define MASCARA_COLOR 0x80
#define MASCARA_PALO  0x30
```

Con esas máscaras, una carta (`carta_origen`) se podrá poner sobre una columna si la carta superior de la columna (`carta_destino`) cumple:

```
(carta_origen & MASCARA_COLOR) != (carta_destino & MASCARA_COLOR)
```

Las columnas, serían algo como:

```
cartas columna1[13] = {NINGUNA_CARTA};
cartas columna2[13] = {NINGUNA_CARTA};
cartas columna3[13] = {NINGUNA_CARTA};
cartas columna4[13] = {NINGUNA_CARTA};
cartas columna5[13] = {NINGUNA_CARTA};
cartas columna6[13] = {NINGUNA_CARTA};
```

La implementación, es cosa tuya :)