# Escalera poker en c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Tengo que hacer un programa que identifique una mano de poker en C++. El usuario va a decir cuantas cartas tiene y escribirá un numero del 0-51, siendo 0 = rey, 1 = as, 2 = dos, 11 = jack, 12 = reina... y 0-12 picas, del 13-25 son diamantes, del 26-38 son corazones y del 39-51 son treboles.

La unica cosa que me falta es un metodo para identificar la escalera sucia, por ejemplo: 2 de treboles(41), 3 picas (3), 4 picas(4), 5 corazones(31) y 6 picas(6). He intentado varias formas, ¿me podriais decir cual seria la mas fácil y rápida?

Comment: "_He intentado varias formas, me podriais decir cual seria la mas facil y rapida?_". Si no compartes las varias formas que has intentado, es imposible decirte cuál de ellas es más rápida o mejor

Comment: Coloca todas las formas (incluyendo el código) que has intentado :D porque tal cual está la pregunta, nos pides que resolvamos tu tarea y eso no hacemos en estos lares :D

Comment: Tal vez puedas sacar alguna idea de [esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21746/2742)

Answer (score 3):

#### Pregunta.

> me falta es un metodo para identificar la escalera sucia

Teniendo en cuenta que cada uno de los palos son del mismo tamaño y tienen un mismo desplazamiento, puedes transformar una mano cualquiera en picas y comprobar si la diferencia entre cada carta de la mano (ordenada) es de una unidad.

#### Propuesta.

Por desgracia no aportas NADA de tu código así que todo son conjeturas y puede que la respuesta no se ajuste del todo a tus necesidades; asumo que las cartas son de tipo `std::uint8_t` y que la mano del jugador es un `std::vector` de esos tipos:

```
using Carta = std::uint8_t;
using Mano = std::vector<Carta>;

bool escalera_sucia(const Mano &mano)
{
    Mano temporal, palo;

    // Transformamos toda la mano a Picas y a Palo
    for (const auto &carta : mano)
    {
        temporal.push_back(carta % 13u);
        palo.push_back(carta / 13);
    }

    // Comprobamos si la mano es sucia (tiene al menos dos palos)
    if (std::all_of(palo.begin(), palo.end(), [i = palo[0]](Carta &c) { return c == i;} ))
        return false;

    // Ordenamos la mano resultante.
    std::sort(temporal.begin(), temporal.end());

    /* Nos aseguramnos que entre carta y carta de la
    mano ordenada, haya solo una unidad de diferencia */
    for (Mano::size_type indice = 1u; indice < temporal.size(); ++indice)
        if ((temporal[indice] - temporal[indice - 1u]) != 1u)
            /* Si llegamos aqui, significa que en algun momento la
            diferencia entre una carta y la siguiente es mayor a 1 */
            return false;

    // Si llegamos aqui, la mano es una escalera sucia.
    return true;
}
```

Para transformar en Picas (el palo base) basta con hacer el modulo entre el total de cartas por palo (`13`), para saber a qué palo pertenece una carta tan solo basta con dividir entre las cartas de cada palo (`13`) siendo `0` picas, `1` diamantes, `2` corazones y `3` tréboles. Una escalera será sucia si al menos hay dos palos en la mano y si la mano es ascendente.

#### Advertencia.

No me se las normas del Póker, así que el algoritmo anterior puede estar mal al considerar que el Rey (valores `0`, `13`, `26` y `39`) va antes que el As. Esto se podría solucionar poniendo el Rey al final de las cartas cambiando el orden a `0` - `9` números normales, `10` Jack, `11` Reina, `12` Rey, etc...

Comment: El único problema que le veo es que va a identificar la escalera normal como escalera sucia

Comment: Buen punto, intento corregirlo (aunque creo que será fútil, pues la pregunta está muerta).

Answer (score 2):

Yo personalmente prefiero manejar datos tratados antes que datos crudos... una cosa es que el usuario tenga que identificar una carta con un número y otra que tu tengas, necesariamente, que usar ese número dentro de tus algoritmos:

```
enum class Palo
{
  Picas,
  Diamantes,
  Corazones,
  Treboles
};

class Carta
{
public:

  explicit Carta(int numero)
    : palo_{static_cast<Palo>(numero/13)},
      numero_{numero%13}
  { }

  Carta(int numero, Palo palo)
    : palo_{palo},
      numero_{numero}
  { }

  Palo GetPalo() const
  { return palo_; }

  int GetNumero() const
  { return numero_; }

private:

  Palo palo_;
  int numero_;
};
```

Por otro lado detectar una escalera sucia tiene su miga:

- Con la secuencia de cartas que has puesto, el rey parece que es la primera carta cuando para el poker es la última
- El AS puede iniciar una escalera (A 2 3 4 5) o finalizarla (10 J Q K A)
- Si todas las cartas son del mismo palo no puede ser una escalera sucia

Con todo esto en mente un posible algoritmo (compilable en C++14) sería el siguiente:

```
bool escalera_sucia(std::vector<Carta> mano)
{
  Palo palo = mano.front().GetPalo();
  bool soloUnPalo = std::all_of(mano.begin(),mano.end(),
                                [palo](Carta const& carta)
                                { return carta.GetPalo() == palo; });

  // No puede ser escalera sucia si todas las cartas son del mismo palo
  if( soloUnPalo )
    return false;

  // Dado que lo siguiente SI es una escalera...
  // - 9 10 J Q K, siendo K = 0
  // ... y que lo siguiente NO es una escalera
  // - K A 2 3 4, siendo K = 0 y A = 1
  // La ordenación ideal requiere poner la K al final del mazo:
  // A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K
  auto sortLambda = [](Carta const& a, Carta const& b)
  {
    if( a.GetNumero() == 0 ) return false;
    if( b.GetNumero() == 0 ) return true;

    return a.GetNumero() < b.GetNumero();
  };

  std::sort(mano.begin(),mano.end(),sortLambda);

  // Lambda anidada.
  // - detectorEscaleraLambda: Una lambda que permite configurar correctamente la lambda anidada
  //                           hay que facilitarle el numero de la primera carta de la secuencia.
  // - lambda anidada: función que comprueba que en una secuencia de cartas sus números son correlativos.
  auto detectorEscaleraLambda = [](int numeroInicial)
  {
    return [numero = numeroInicial](Carta const& carta) mutable
    {
      bool toReturn = (carta.GetNumero() == numero);
      numero = (numero+1) % 13;
      return toReturn;
    };
  };

  bool escalera = std::all_of(mano.begin(),mano.end(),detectorEscaleraLambda(mano.front().GetNumero()));

  if( !escalera )
  {
    // La combinación A 10 J Q K no puede se encontrada con el orden actual de la mano
    if( mano.front().GetNumero() == 1 )
    {
      // Ponemos la primera carta en la ultima posicion, luego A 10 J Q K se convierte en 10 J Q K A
      Carta carta = mano.front();
      mano.erase(mano.begin());
      mano.push_back(carta);

      // Y volvemos a comprobar la escalera
      escalera = std::all_of(mano.begin(),mano.end(),detectorEscaleraLambda(mano.front().GetNumero()));
    }
  }
  return escalera;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando <kbd>[aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fmpGenhXqyKNZZGx)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Esta opción usa un `std::set`, aprovechándose de que sus elementos son únicos y ordenados.

Para forma una escalera "sucia", el primer paso es completar ese set con los números de los naipes, abstrayéndose de sus "palos".

La primera condición es que no haya ningún número repetido.

La segunda condición es que si forman escalera, deben cumplir con:
ultimo - primero = cantidad - 1;

Entonces:

```
bool es_escalera_sucia(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::set<int> mano;

    for (auto& n : v) {  
        mano.insert(n % 13);
    }

    if (mano.size() != v.size())  
        return false;

    return *mano.rbegin() - *mano.begin() == v.size() - 1;
}
```

Comment: faltaría verificar que no es una escalera (una escalera no sucia)

Comment: Puede ser @Mariano, o no, dependerá también de otras circunstancias. Supongo que también podría pensarse en comprobar que el vector del parámetro tenga la cantidad de naipes que se espera. En general, cualquiera de mis respuestas aquí, y en la vida en general, son más bien de carácter relativo; si alguna vez parecieran taxativas, por favor, tomarlas sólo como una forma de expresión enfática.

Answer (score -2):

Considera cambiar el formato de las cartas. En lugar de usar un entero (`int`) usa una pareja de enteros (`std::pair <int, int>`). En donde el primer elemento es el número de la carta (rey:0, as:0, 2:2, ...) y el segundo es el color (picas:0, diamantes:1, corazones:2 y tréboles:3). Puedes acceder a los valores de la pareja mediante `.first` y `.second`

```
int carta_int;
std::pair <int, int> carta_par;
carta_par.first = carta_int % 13;
carta_par.second = carta_int / 4;
```

Saludos

Comment: Esto no soluciona el tema de la escalera, que es lo que el OP pregunta ...

Comment: Además de lo comentado por @lois6b... para rellenar una `pair` tenemos `std::make_pair` que requiere solo una línea de código... menos código, más legible, menos problemas